# How to fix badboxes aligning wide figure in the marginpart

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

I want to align a figure in the left marginpar. I found a way using marginpar{/includegraphics}. However there are two things not coded correct.

- The figure (blackbox) is wider compared to the marginwidth, which gives a badbox. 'Overfull \hbox (60.98819pt too wide) in paragraph'
- And since I dont succeed in combining a figure environment with the \marginpar{} the text around the figure doesnt contain with space like normally.

Below my MWE.

Does somebody know a good way to provide an environmont for the figure in a way its aligned in the left marginpar, doesnt created badbox and has some blank space around it like a normal figure?

Thanks in advance!!

```
    \documentclass{scrreprt}

    \usepackage[
     includemp,
     showframe,
     reversemp,
     paperwidth=20.10cm,
     paperheight=25.80cm,
     top=2.30cm,
     bottom=3.4cm,
     inner=2.7cm,
     outer=2.7cm,
     marginparwidth=1.6cm, % Fixed for now
     marginparsep=0.4cm
     ]{geometry}

     \usepackage{lipsum}
     \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage{marginfix}

     \makeatletter          
     \let\Gm@vrules@mpi\Gm@vrules@mpii
     \makeatother % to set the marginpar on the left side in showframe

     \begin{document}

     \lipsum[1]

     \marginpar{
     \includegraphics[width=10cm]{blackbox}
      }

      \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the `changepage` package and use this code, which should do the trick:

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}{}
\noindent\includegraphics{my graphic file}
\end{adjustwidth}
```